# T-SQL - get date by dynamic params

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I tried to figure out a dynamic query to get date col within past 20 days. The idea is quite simple and, moreover, I know the table does contain dates from getdate() to -20 days but still no result get returned

```
DECLARE @date_past_period varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @date_past_number varchar(MAX);
SET @date_past_period='day';
SET @date_past_number='20';

DECLARE @aDate datetime;

DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
SET @sql='SELECT date FROM table WHERE convert(varchar,date,121) BETWEEN convert(varchar,getdate(),121) AND convert(varchar,dateadd('+@date_past_period+', -'+@date_past_number+', getdate()),121)';


exec(@sql);
```

Maybe the problem is in dynamic thing but I am not sure.

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: not sure why you don't use a stored procedure and bypass `exec`.

Comment: It is a test snippet. And the db date col contains saved values format like "02 Oct 2008 11:02:07:577 " the incoming params are expected in different format like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm" so I tried to make a common format in this way. Of course I am not sure it is an optimal way so if you can advice a better one do this please :)

Comment: Might I suggest adding a few variables?  Call GETDATE() only once, then calculate the starting and ending dates from that date/time.  Use those in the query to check the [date] column without converting it to a string.  Thus the optimizer could use a (gasp) index to efficiently locate the desired rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this scenario can be covered without using dynamic SQL, however, one obvious problem in your SQL is the between clause - the range is in the wrong order. Try changing your @sql as below:

```
SET @sql='SELECT date FROM table WHERE convert(varchar,date,121) BETWEEN convert(varchar,dateadd('+@date_past_period+', -'+@date_past_number+', getdate()),121) AND convert(varchar,getdate(),121)';
```

Comment: No it can't be non-dynamic because params like day/week/month etc in dateadd function must be variable anyway :) Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Oh, great! The order problem was :) It worked now but still I am thinking of the optimization. Is it OK I tried to bring all to common date format in this way?

Comment: @user592704: If your answer is solved, consider checking it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) function (T-SQL):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure 
@IntervalType VARCHAR(15),
@Num INT
AS

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = 
    CASE @IntervalType
        WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY,@Num,@StartDate)
        WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,@Num,@StartDate)
        WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATEADD(YEAR,@Num,@StartDate)
    END;

IF @EndDate IS NULL
    RAISERROR('Invalid params', 16, 1);
ELSE
    SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

By converting to `VARCHAR` your search condition from `WHERE` will not be SARG ( [1](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/are-you-in-tune-) & [2](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/inside-search-arguments) ).

Comment: +1 This is the better answer in my opinion, because it protects against sql injection, whereas the other answer does not.